# printing Unicode characters C++

Tags: c++, unicode

I'm trying to write a simple command line app to teach myself Japanese, but can't seem to get Unicode characters to print.  What am I missing?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        wcout << L"こんにちは世界\n";
        wcout << L"Hello World\n"
        system("pause");
}
```

In this example only "Press any key to continue" is displayed.  Tested on Visual C++ 2013.

Comment: Windows doesn't allow Unicode output to a terminal window unless you use the `chcp 65001` command and even then it isn't guaranteed to work properly. I have no idea what the C++ runtime with `wcout` adds to the mix.

Comment: That will work, so does SetConsoleCP().  The trouble is finding a font that is fixed-pitch and also supports Japanese glyphs.  Consolas and Lucida on a Western machines don't.

Comment: I tried system("chcp 65001") but that didn't work either...

Comment: The common way to turn on wide string printing on the Windows console is to execute `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_WTEXT);`. Naturally, you need a font that supports the characters, too (and if you don't have one, you would still be able to redirect the output to a file and open it with Notepad) See [MSDN for details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw4k6df8.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

This is not easy on Windows. Even when you manage to get the text to the Windows console you still need to configure cmd.exe to be able to display Japanese characters.

---

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "こんにちは世界\n";
}
```

This works fine on any system where:

- The compiler's source and execution encodings include the characters.
- The output device (e.g., the console) expects text in the same encoding as the compiler's execution encoding.
- A font with the appropriate characters is available (usually not a problem).

Most platforms these days use UTF-8 by default for all these encodings and so can support the entire Unicode range with code similar to the above. Unfortunately Windows is not one of these platforms.

```
wcout << L"こんにちは世界\n";
```

In this line the string literal data is (at compile time) converted from the source encoding to the execution wide encoding and then (at run time) `wcout` uses the locale it is imbued with to convert the wchar_t data to char data for output. Where things go wrong is that the default locale is only required to support characters from the basic source character set, which doesn't even include all ASCII characters, let alone non-ASCII characters.

So the conversion results in an error, putting `wcout` into a bad state. The error has to be cleared before wcout will function again, which is why the second print statement does not output anything.

---

You can work around this for a limited range of characters by imbuing `wcout` with a locale that will successfully convert the characters. Unfortunately the encoding that is needed to support the entire Unicode range this way is UTF-8; Although Microsoft's implementation of streams supports other multibyte encodings it very specifically does not support UTF-8.

For example:

```
wcout.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::classic(), new std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>()));

SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);

wcout << L"こんにちは世界\n";
```

Here `wcout` will correctly convert the string to UTF-8, and if the output were written to a file instead of the console then the file would contain the correct UTF-8 data. However the Windows console, even though configured here to accept UTF-8 data, simply will not accept UTF-8 data written in this way.

---

There are a few options:

- Avoid the standard library entirely:

  ```
  DWORD n;
  WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), L"こんにちは世界\n", 8, &n, nullptr);
  ```
- Use non-standard magical incantation that will break standard code:

  ```
  #include <fcntl.h>
  #include <io.h>

  _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U8TEXT);
  std::wcout << L"こんにちは世界\n";
  ```

  After setting this mode `std::cout << "Hello, World";` will crash.
- Use a low level IO API along with manual conversion:

  ```
  #include <codecvt>
  #include <locale>

  SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
  std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>, wchar_t> convert;
  std::puts(convert.to_bytes(L"こんにちは世界\n"));
  ```

Using any of these methods, cmd.exe will display the correct text to the best of its ability, by which I mean it will display unreadable boxes. Seven little boxes, for the given string.

[image: Little Boxes]

You can copy the text out of cmd.exe and into notepad.exe or whatever to see the correct glyphs.

Comment: Why is this? I can correctly print any kind of character up to U+2095, but after that the console fails even if the font contains the correct glyphs for it. Is this problem solvable by any means?

Comment: @Banderi I'm not reproducing your problem. E.g. `WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), L"\uFFFD", 1, &n, nullptr);` works for me and shows the correct character (when I copy the square from the console into notepad.exe).

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. I want to display them correctly, not print them correctly. The printing to the console - and subsequent copypaste - goes perfectly well, but what about those squares? Why is the console not able to show the glyph?

Comment: @Banderi Okay, what font are you using and what character are you trying to display?

Comment: I've tried _Consolas_ and _Lucida Console_ and I'm trying to display Japanese characters. Every Unicode character after U+2095 will act the same though.

Comment: @Banderi I believe the issue you're seeing is that Consolas and Lucida Console do not contain the characters you're attempting to display. cmd.exe is very primitive and unfortunately does not support any kind of font fallback mechanism, so it will only display characters that exist directly in the selected font. Since other programs and text rendering APIs do support font fallback, you may be mislead into thinking fonts contain more characters than they do. Use charmap.exe to check fonts to see what characters they really include.

Answer (score 4):

There's a whole article about dealing with Unicode in Windows console

http://alfps.wordpress.com/2011/11/22/unicode-part-1-windows-console-io-approaches/
http://alfps.wordpress.com/2011/12/08/unicode-part-2-utf-8-stream-mode/

Basically, you may implement you own `streambuf` for `std::cout` (or `std::wcout`) in terms of `WriteConsoleW` and enjoy writing UTF-8 (or whatever Unicode you want) to Windows console without depending on locales, console code pages and even without using wide characters.
It may not look very straightforward, but it's convenient and reusable solution, which is also able to give you a portable utf8-everywhere style user code. Please, don't beat me for my English :)

Answer (score -1):

Or you can change Windows locale to Japanese.