# ASCII characters not printed in WCOUT and COUT

Tags: c++, cout, unicode-string

I am trying to print some "special" characters (above 127) in the console, but somehow it doesn't get printed.

I have this small code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::wcout << L"a■■■■■■■■■■■a■■■■■■■■■■■■■■a" << std::flush;
    return 0;
}
```

it prints the 'a' but then... nothing. and it doesn't matter if I use cout/string or wcout/wstring. (with cout I only see "?" and in wcout nothing, it ends the stream)

The ascii code is 254 for this character. What can be happening here? I thought this is okay to print?

Comment: There's quite a bit of code here that doesn't seem to contribute to the question. Does this **really** only happen when you run this code in its own thread? With all the waits? Don't stop refining the test case until it is **really** the smallest that compiles and runs and shows the problem.

Comment: @PeteBecker alright updated

Comment: Try adding `std::setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");` at the beginning of your main function (needs `<clocale>`).

Comment: @KerrekSB seems `std::setlocale(0,"");` (needs 2 parameters? with one doesn't compile) changes it to a "working" state in terms of the stream not terminating, but the `■` character is being printed as `|`, what about that?

Comment: @Gizmo: Sorry, fixed.

Comment: @KerrekSB seems it's still printing the square as vertical line, looking into the reference now

Comment: What compiler are you using and on what system?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Windows 8 Microsoft Visual C++ 11 (VS2012)

Comment: possible duplicate of [printing Unicode characters C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904081/printing-unicode-characters-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the answer I linked to in the comments, I think this is your solution:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>

_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U8TEXT);
```