# How can I get and print the nth character of a wchar_t?

Tags: c, windows, unicode

given:

```
wchar_t* str = L"wide chars";
```

how get i extract one character at a time in c (not c++)?

for example, I tried

```
for (int i = 0; i < wcslen(str); i++) {
    printf("%wc\n", str[i]);
}
```

But only gave me gibberish

Comment: This is because `%wc` should be `%lc` ([demo](http://ideone.com/05ewa1)). Closing as a typo.

Comment: its still doesn't work if str = "日本語" for example

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: In that case, my answer might help, or you might need something more windows specific. I don't know much about windows, sorry. I'll add some tags.

Comment: I do know that wchar_t in Windows can only hold codes which fit in the BMP; if you need other planes (i.e. codes greater than U+FFFF), then you'll end up with surrogate pairs, and individual characters from a surrogate pair are not meaningful.

Comment: 日本語 characters are all in BMP.

Comment: It isn't impossible to use Unicode in the console on Windows, but it generally seems to be more trouble than it's worth.  Consider using the GUI instead, e.g., MessageBox.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3780378/694576 http://stackoverflow.com/q/1371012/694576 http://stackoverflow.com/q/18904081/694576

Answer (score 2):

On Linux (Ubuntu), the following worked fine:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main() {
  /* See below */
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
  wchar_t* str = L"日本語";
  for (int i = 0; i < wcslen(str); i++) {
        printf("U+%04x: %lc\n", str[i], str[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The `setlocale` call is important. Without it, the program will execute in the C locale, in which there is no wide character to multibyte conversion, which is necessary for the `%lc` format code. `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` causes the process's locale to be set to the defaults defined by the various environment variables.

Comment: Note that this won't work on Windows in the astral plane, because `wchar_t` on Windows is UTF-16.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Indeed. I wrote that answer before I know that the target OS was Windows. Perhaps I should move my comment about surrogate pairs into the answer. TBH, I don't know if it will work on Windows even without surrogate pairs.

Comment: Code above worked for me in Windows 7 if the source was saved in UTF-8 with BOM, except the characters didn't print because I'm not on Japanese Windows.  The codepoints were correct.